# Correlation analysis between bands in a RasterStack using Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, correlation

I am working with several variables in GEE and I would like to do a correlation analysis with them. I have constructed a Raster Stack with the variables and then I sampled the region with 10.000 points to make the analysis. The code looks like something like this:

```
var colombia = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Colombia')); #countries is LSIB 2017: Large Scale International Boundary Polygons, Simplified 
var band1 = ee.Image('users/yourecoveredinbees/osm_earth/dir_highway_footway_density_300mA').clip(colombia);
var band2 = ee.Image('users/yourecoveredinbees/osm_earth/dir_highway_tertiary_density_300mA').clip(colombia);
var band3 = ee.Image('users/yourecoveredinbees/osm_earth/dir_landuse_industrial_PG_density_300m').clip(colombia);

var stack = band1.addBands(band2).addBands(band3);

var correl = ee.Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation(stack);
```

When I´m trying to run the last line, GEE show me an error that says: **Too many (1) arguments to function: Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation() Creates a two-input reducer that computes Pearson's product-moment correlation coefficient and the 2-sided p-value test for correlation = 0.**

Can you help with this error or maybe suggest another way to display the correlation analysis with this kind of variables?

Comment: Thanks for making your assets sharable! In the future, could you be sure to check whether the code you post can be run without any changes? The first line has a `#` which should be a `//` in javascript commenting. Also, `countries` is not defined. You could post the code block into a Earth Engine script and use the `Get Link` button to share the minimal code example.

Comment: @SeanCarter Thank you so much for your help and I´m sorry for the mistakes in my question, I have been learning in posting here and your answer will help me to improve even more. Your code runs perfectly and I would like to ask you: Do yo know how can I make a matrix with the correlations of all the bands, maybe with a loop or a function? Thank you so much again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that the `ee.Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation()` function does not require any arguments. When you call it in `var correl = ee.Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation(stack)`, you give it an argument that it doesn't need.

Also, you won't be able to run a the correlation reducer to the image itself because the reducer has two inputs. From the docs of `ee.Image.reduce()`:

> The reducer must have a single input and will be called at each pixel to reduce the stack of band values.

In order to run the `pearsonsCorrelation` reducer, you have to first create a sample (which you said you did?) feature collection and select two properties from which you want to find the correlation.

Here is my (untested) code:

```
var band1 = ee.Image('users/yourecoveredinbees/osm_earth/dir_highway_footway_density_300mA').clip(colombia);
var band2 = ee.Image('users/yourecoveredinbees/osm_earth/dir_highway_tertiary_density_300mA').clip(colombia);
var band3 = ee.Image('users/yourecoveredinbees/osm_earth/dir_landuse_industrial_PG_density_300m').clip(colombia);



var stack = band1.addBands(band2).addBands(band3);

// Here, sample the stack:
var sample = stack.sample({'region':columbia, 
                            'scale': 1000, 
                            'projection': 'EPSG:4326',
                            'numPixels':100})

// Call reducer correctly:
var correl = ee.Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation();

// Then choose two properties to see the correlation:
var reduced = sample.reduceColumns(correl, ['band1', 'band2'])

print(reduced)
```